# get columns of table start with something and their data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

eg : table    student

```
name    age     age1    age2
aname   1       2       3
bname   2       3       3
```

I want

```
age     age1    age2
1       2       3
2       3       3
```

I can get columns like by

```
select column_name from information_schema 
where column like 'age%' and table_name ='student'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: @this is the business case .I tried to explain using example

Comment: If I understand correctly you'll need a stored proc with dynamic SQL. You'll define a cursor of columns from information schema, loop through that appending the column name to a query string, then execute.

Comment: i also gave the thought about stored proc but is there any other way @Error_2646

Comment: Nope. Maybe there is some voodoo solution, but I've never seen this done any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dynamic SQL, use `STUFF` to combine all your columns, then use `execute` function execute SQL dynamically.

```
CREATE TABLE student(
  name varchar(50),
  age int,
  age1 int,
  age2 int
);

insert into student values ('aname',1,2,3);
insert into student values ('bname',2,3,3);

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT distinct ', '+ COLUMN_NAME
            from information_schema.columns 
            where COLUMN_NAME like 'age%' and table_name ='student'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM student '
execute(@query)
```

[sqlifddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ed90f7127d6a8da89232c5735d62bb81)